# Simple std::promise example not working on MSVC

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2015, promise, future

I'm trying to run the example from [the cppreference wiki](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) on MSVC 2015, but it always crashes ("abort() has been called") when f3.get() is called, where f3 is the std::future object retrieved from a std::promise. Is this a bug from Visual Studio ?

Here's my Call Stack:

```
ucrtbased.dll!000007fee5451a05()    Unknown
ucrtbased.dll!000007fee5451ba3()    Unknown
ucrtbased.dll!000007fee5472b7d()    Unknown
ucrtbased.dll!000007fee5471bca()    Unknown
vcruntime140d.dll!000007fef8b84494()    Unknown
vcruntime140d.dll!000007fef8b8651d()    Unknown
vcruntime140d.dll!000007fef8b9714a()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!00000000771e7e8d()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!00000000771d84cf()    Unknown
ntdll.dll!000000007720bac8()    Unknown
KernelBase.dll!000007fefd08a06d()   Unknown
vcruntime140d.dll!000007fef8b881c0()    Unknown
msvcp140d.dll!000007fef01d2ebe()    Unknown
msvcp140d.dll!000007fef01d2e4f()    Unknown
>Sandbox.exe!std::_Check_C_return(int _Res) Line 36 C++
Sandbox.exe!std::_Mtx_lockX(_Mtx_internal_imp_t * _Mtx) Line 71 C++
Sandbox.exe!std::_Mutex_base::lock() Line 44    C++
Sandbox.exe!std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock<std::mutex>(std::mutex & _Mtx) Line 274   C++
Sandbox.exe!std::_Associated_state<int>::_Set_exception(std::exception_ptr _Exc, bool _At_thread_exit) Line 414 C++
Sandbox.exe!std::_State_manager<int>::_Set_exception(std::exception_ptr _Exc, bool _Defer) Line 1054    C++
Sandbox.exe!std::promise<int>::~promise<int>() Line 1518    C++
Sandbox.exe!main::__l3::<lambda>(std::promise<int> p) Line 23   C++
[External Code]
```

Comment: You have an error in your code.

Comment: It's not my code...
If you're referring to the code from cppreference, it actually seems to work when you launch the online compiler test (for what it's worth).

Comment: I assume before posting you tried to generate a [MCVE], right?  As such, no subset of the code you copied from cppreference cause this problem?  Only exactly that code, with no parts removed?

Comment: That's LWG 2532, edited cppreference to keep the promise past wait

Comment: Indeed @Yakk , I strictly copied & pasted the example from cppreference into my main.cpp

Comment: @user6381026 Please take the effort to generate a [MCVE] as well, then post that MCVE here.  Knowing that you started with the cppreference source is still useful, but a MCVE is going to be the first step someone trying to help you is probably going to have to do, and you are almost as qualified as they are to make it.

Comment: @Cubbi that was it, it works now! Thanks.